# Facebook finally enabled hashtags on timeline - any search/stream APIs available yet?

Tags: facebook, social-networking, hashtag

So facebook have finally enabled hashtags on the timeline.

an example URL on how to access a hashtag is via https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/china

Regardless of what I think of it - I was wondering how to search those hashtags and what programming tools would be available to us?

Anything similar to twitter search API or twitter streaming APIs ?

My basic google and facebook dev search did not reveal any findings (or i was too excited to notice)

Comment: Didn't find anything in API docs, hopefully we will be getting it soon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we track hashtags with the new facebook hashtag implementation](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/17114210/how-can-we-track-hashtags-with-the-new-facebook-hashtag-implementation)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something like this perhaps?

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23hashtag&type=post

Source:
http://www.staynalive.com/2013/06/developers-heres-how-you-access.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think fb has enabled hashtags. The url provided returned 404. 
Thank you.

Comment: i think it may not be rolled out to all users yet maybe. I just double checked it and yap - it gives a page with china hashtags

Answer (score 0):

The URL `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23hashtag&type=post` does return JSON for the search string #hastag with my account logged in.  I would try FB as a sample to see what you get.

ex. `"https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23fb&type=post"` will return all the most recent posts with "fb" in them regardless of a hastag being in front.

I do seem to get different results when logged in versus logged out.  I was one of the early people to get access to graph search so your mileage may vary.

*Interesting details*:

- If the search you are doing has NO hashtag content available it will return results from just the keyword.
- It does not seem to separate out the hashtag that was requested in the JSON and the results for a request of multiple hashtags will AND the results not OR them
- Paging information is included in the returned JSON using Unix timestamps

ex:

```
"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=\u002523fb&type=post&limit=25&until=1373055352"
```